# Why doesn't the --conf parameter work in yarn-cluster mode (but works in yarn-client and local)?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

According to [Spark Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/submitting-applications.html):

```
--conf: Arbitrary Spark configuration property in key=value format. For values that contain spaces wrap “key=value” in quotes (as shown).
```

And indeed, when I use that parameter, in my Spark program I can retrieve the value of the key by using:

```
System.getProperty("key");
```

This works when I test my program locally, and also in yarn-client mode; I can log the **value** of the **key** and see that it matches what I wrote in the command line, but it returns **null** when I submit the very same program in **yarn-cluster** mode.

Why can't I retrieve the value of key given as `--conf "key=value"` when I submit my Spark application in **yarn-cluster** mode?

Any ideas and/or workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, via `--conf` you should pass only Spark-specific properties. If you want to pass an arbitrary key, value pair then you should pass them like:

```
--driver-java-options "-Dkey=someValue"
```

and then you can retrieve the value of the key via:

```
System.getProperty("key");
```